# Objective-C - iOS - Singleton explanation

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, singleton

this is the code of my singleton

```
+ (ALData *)sharedInstance {

    static ALData *_shared;
    if(!_shared) {
        static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
        dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^ {
            _shared = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
        });
    }

    return _shared;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone { return [self sharedInstance]; }
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone { return self; }
#if (!__has_feature(objc_arc))
- (id)retain { return self; }
- (unsigned)retainCount { return UINT_MAX; }
- (void)release {}
- (id)autorelease { return self; }
#endif
```

Now, all the singletons I have seen are being called in this way :

```
[[SINGLETON sharedInstance] instanceMethod];
```

But I want to call in this way :

```
[SINGLETON classMethod];
```

To do this when I create my method I do this :

```
+ (BOOL)decide:(BOOL)var {
    [self sharedInstance];
    if (var)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}
```

Instead, if I want to proceed in the first way I have to declare my method in this way :

```
- (BOOL)decide:(BOOL)var {
    if (var)
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}
```

and when I call it I have to write :

```
[[SINGLETON sharedInstance] decide:YES];
```

My question is : what is the difference between these two approaches? Both in terms of performance, both at the level of design pattern.
I would like to know this because I think that aesthetically the better method is the second, the one that doesn't call the `sharedInstance`.

I hope my question is clear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188982/singleton-instance-vs-class-methods

Comment: There is no relation between your two examples. First one calls the Class method (There is no need of that first line, why you wrote that ?) and another one calls the instance method on singleton instance

Comment: Terrible examples. Your `+decide:` method gets the shared instance, doesn't assign it to anything, and doesn't need the instance anyway. Your `-decide:` method might as well be a class method as it doesn't rely at all on the state of the object. Please post real code instead of a phony example.

Comment: @MidhunMP I don't think it's terrible, why is it terrible? And, why there's no relation between the two examples? One is a class method and the other one is an instance method, one need to be called after the sharedInstance and the other one can be called as a class method because call the sharedInstance itself.

Comment: @AndreaLufino: Why are you calling the `[self sharedInstance];` inside the class method ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Because I thought I need to call it, but now I understand that I don't need to create the sharedInstance method if I want to use only class methods, is it right?

Comment: @AndreaLufino: Yes, you are right :)

Comment: What is `decide` supposed to do??  It's just returning it's input parameter.  If you need to do that for some strange reason, just make it a macro.

Comment: (The first thing to ask is:  Why do you need a singleton at all???  They are used far too often to "solve" nonexistent problems.)

Comment: @HotLicks decide was only an example method that could be anything else. Now I solve my doubt and I clear ideas and understand the difference between singleton and class with only class methods

Comment: If your question is "Is it OK to have a class that has only class methods, and is never instantiated?", the answer is yes -- it's perfectly fine.  I wouldn't say it's done "all the time", but it's not terribly unusual.  It's a good way, eg, to cluster together a set of related "utility" functions.

Comment: @HotLicks Good, and as I understand, a singleton is good to store data because has the advantages to have one only instance, is it right?

Comment: That is correct, so far as it goes.  But there are lots of other ways to have only one instance, in well-designed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between a `Singleton` and a Class with a bunch of Class methods is that the `Singleton` can preserve some kind of state. For example, an array of data or some boolean flags. By calling `sharedInstance`, you access to the one and only **instance** of this class, that is being kept alive(and the state of the data is preserved there). You can certainly add some class methods to your singleton class and they will work, but you will escape the `Singleton` pattern.

Comment: So, the way that need to call the sharedInstance is the real singleton pattern, right? The other one is a "simple" class with its class methods, right?

Comment: @AndreaLufino Yes. In the first case you are calling an instance method on the singleton object that preserves some state. In the second case, you are calling a Class method.

Comment: Good, now this is clear. But one more question. If the 2nd case is a class with its class methods, do I need to write the sharedInstance method on top and call it in every class method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a property that returns the shared instance, then just call that.

```
-(YourSingleton *)sharedStore
{
    return [Singleton sharedInstance];
}
```

Then call

```
[self.sharedStore decide:YES];
```