# What is this design pattern called where methods are instance methods and not class methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

```
 NSData *_dataArchive = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] 
                                        objectForKey:@"Session"];
```

This style is pretty common in Obj-C.

Why is it [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] someMethod]? Here someMethod is InstanceMethod?

Why not [NSUserDefaults someMethod]? here someMethod is Class method.

Answer (score 4):

Your confusion may be that you believe there can only be one `NSUserDefaults`. This isn't true. The original design of `NSUserDefaults` included the ability to fetch the defaults for a particular user with `initWithUser:`. This was never implemented (and is now deprecated), but it demonstrates the limitation you'd face if it'd been designed with class methods.

In the latest Foundation, there's a new `initWithSuiteName:` which can be used to share defaults between related applications. So it's nice that we didn't have that limitation, even if it took decades to be actually used.

There's an important lesson here for designing your own APIs. In general it's better to have easily accessed instances ("shared...", etc.) rather than forcing a single instance that you can never expand on.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a design pattern. It's just the normal way you call methods on an object instance.

Think of the code this way:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSDate *dataArchive = [defaults objectForKey:@"Session"];
```

It's just a normal method call.

It's not `[NSUserDefaults someMethod]` because `objectForKey:` needs to be called on a specific instance of `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 2):

The key issue here is that having a bunch of class methods is less flexible than a bunch of instance methods of a single shared instance. What if you subsequently decide that you want to allow multiple instances? In this shared instance pattern, this is trivial, but in the class method approach it may require considerable refactoring. Furthermore, in this case, where we can reset the standard user defaults, that's a somewhat intuitive in the context of a shared instance that is getting released, but is less clear in a case of a class without any instances. What exactly is getting reset?

In terms of the name of this pattern, this shared instance returned by `standardUserDefaults` is very similar to the singleton pattern. In fact, the debate of class methods vs instance methods of a shared instance are usually discussed in the context of singletons, which are the prototypical example of a class with a single shared instance. But `NSUserDefaults` deviates a bit from the singleton pattern (partially for reasons that Rob Napier discussed, also because singletons don't contemplate their deallocation, which `resetStandardUserDefaults` can do). This specific `NSUserDefaults` pattern doesn't have a commonly accepted name (beyond something informal, such as "a resettable shared instance").

So, if you're looking for more information debating the pros and cons of these two approaches, I'd suggest we focus less on the idiosyncratic details of `NSUserDefaults`: I'd suggest you search for "singleton vs class methods" and you'll find links such as [Singleton Instance vs Class Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13188982/1271826).

Answer (score 2):

After reading your last two question, I get an impression that you are not completely aware of `Singletons`.

`Singleton` design pattern is on of the widely used pattern for various use cases while making app (eg. Maintaining the login session and data for currently logged in user, etc.). In this pattern, you make a class and initialize it in such a specific way that one and only one instance of it can be created. So when you initialize `NSUserDefaults *abc = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` for the first time, an instance/object of class `NSUserDefaults` is created in memory. Now, when you do any initialization after first one, say `NSUserDefaults *xyz = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`, instead of creating new instance of class `NSUserDefaults`, the already created instance is returned. So both, `abc` and `xyz` will be holding same instance in the memory; both will not represent two separate instance.

Addressing your concern of the method, so here, the method `objectForKey:` is the instance method which is called upon the instance of the object. Therefore, you first get the singleton instance by `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and then call the method on this instance.